# smtpclient not working for exchange server but works for smtp server

Tags: c#, .net, smtp

I have written a very basic class to send an email. I tested that with smtp server and it works fine, but when I try to use my company's exchange server it giving this exception:

The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.1 Client was not authenticated

My code is as below:

```
MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage("From@company.com", "To@company.com", "Test Subject", "Void body");
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(smtpServerAddress, smtpServerPort);
NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential(AccountName,Password);
smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtpClient.Credentials = credentials;
smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate(object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; }; // without this I get: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
```

Do I need to handle exchange server differently than smtp server.

Please advice
Thanks

Comment: Most likely, the Exchange server needs to have some configuration done to allow you to use it.  There are a number of things that could result in such an error.  (SMTP pass-through not enabled, configuration rules about which servers/users are allowed to use pass-through, etc).  This is probably a better fit at ServerFault.com.  Googling the error gives instructions for resolving this by changing the Exchange server's configuration.  http://smtp25.blogspot.com/2009/04/530-571-client-was-not-authenticated.html

Comment: What is the value of smtpServerPort?

Comment: @DavidStratton But the same exchange server works with outlook.

Comment: Outlook uses MAPI, not SMTP by default.  http://it.med.miami.edu/x1111.xml  Two different protocols, like http vs. ftp.  A web server running IIS can have http enabled and ftp disabled.  Likewise, an Exchange Server can have MAPI enaled, and SMTP disabled.  Also, SMPT is usually locked down so that only certain, specifically allowed users and machines can use it as a pass-through server, in order to prevent malicious programs from spamming using the server.  The settings for each are distinct.  Setting permissions to use MAPI does not mean the same permissions apply to SMTP.

Answer (score 3):

Are you using the right port number?

> **Protocol: SMTP/SSL**
>
> •Port (TCP/UDP): 465 (TCP)
>
> •Description: SMTP over SSL. TCP port 465 is reserved by common
>   industry practice for secure SMTP communication using the SSL
>   protocol. However, unlike IMAP4, POP3, NNTP, and HTTP, SMTP in
>   Exchange 2000 does not use a separate port for secure communication
>   (SSL), but rather, employs an "in-band security sub-system" called
>   Transport Layer Security (TLS). To enable TLS to work on Exchange
>   2000, you must install a Computer certificate on the Exchange 2000
>   server.

Ripped from here: http://www.petri.co.il/ports_used_by_exchange.htm

Comment: But I can use that exchange server using outlook.. Any ideas?

Comment: Get a client-side proxy (like Fiddler) or WireShark and trap the communication between your box and the exchange server.  This will tell you which ports are in use during the conversation.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem. On your exchange server enter the Exchange System Manager and open the object tree to the server, then protocols, and right click on default SMTP virtual server and select properties. Click the access tab and then the authentication button. Finally click users and make sure that the user that you are using has access to the SMTP Relay. In addition, if you have not done so already select the relay button under the SMTP and make sure that the machine running the application is not blacklisted, or has been granted permission.

Answer (score 0):

I found this post about using exchange to send the email. It appears that he is using the Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices namespace instead. I don't have exchange to test with. Just putting out ideas.

http://waqarsherbhatti.posterous.com/sending-email-using-exchange-server-2010-ews

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try sending using WebDAV. Here's my method if you want to try it out..

```
    public static void ViaWebDav(String sMailbox, String sExchange, String sTo, String sCc, String sSubject, String sBody, params String[] sAttachments)
    {
        HttpWebRequest hwrOut;
        HttpWebResponse hwrIn;

        //String strServer = "SXGM-202.xxx.com";
        //string strPassword = "123";
        //string strUserID = "u";
        //string strDomain = "fg";


        Byte[] b = null;
        Stream s = null;



        String sMailboxUrl = "http://" + sExchange + "/exchange/" + sMailbox;

        String sMailboxSend = sMailboxUrl + "/##DavMailSubmissionURI##/";

        String sMailboxTemp = sMailboxUrl + "/drafts/" + sSubject + ".eml";

        // Construct the RFC 822 formatted body of the PUT request.
        // Note: If the From: header is included here,
        // the MOVE method request will return a
        // 403 (Forbidden) status. The From address will
        // be generated by the Exchange server.
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine("To: " + sTo);
        if (!sCc.IsEmpty()) sb.AppendLine("Cc: " + sCc);
        sb.AppendLine("Subject: " + sSubject);
        sb.AppendLine("Date: " + System.DateTime.Now);
        sb.AppendLine("X-Mailer: AML FIU;");
        sb.AppendLine("MIME-Version: 1.0;");
        sb.AppendLine("Content-Type: text/plain;");
        sb.AppendLine("Charset = \"iso-8859-1\"");
        sb.AppendLine("Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit;");
        sb.AppendLine();
        sb.AppendLine(sBody);

        // Create a new CredentialCache object and fill it with the network
        // credentials required to access the server.
        //MyCredentialCache = new CredentialCache();
        //MyCredentialCache.Add(new System.Uri(strMailboxURI),
        //    "NTLM",
        //    new NetworkCredential(strUserID, strPassword, strDomain)
        //   );

        // Create the HttpWebRequest object.
        hwrOut = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(sMailboxTemp);
        hwrOut.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        hwrOut.Method = "PUT";
        hwrOut.ContentType = "message/rfc822";

        // Encode the body using UTF-8.
        b = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString());

        hwrOut.ContentLength = b.Length;


        s = hwrOut.GetRequestStream();
        s.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
        s.Close();

        // PUT the message in the Drafts folder of the mailbox.
        hwrIn = (HttpWebResponse)hwrOut.GetResponse();


        #region //ATTACHMENTS
        //Do the PROPPATCH
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<?xml version='1.0'?>");
        sb.Append("<d:propertyupdate xmlns:d='DAV:'>");
        sb.Append("<d:set>");
        sb.Append("<d:prop>");
        sb.Append("<isCollection xmlns='DAV:'>False</isCollection>");
        sb.Append("</d:prop>");
        sb.Append("</d:set>");
        sb.Append("</d:propertyupdate>");

        foreach (String sAttach in sAttachments)
        {
            hwrOut = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(sMailboxTemp);
            hwrOut.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            hwrOut.Method = "PROPPATCH";
            hwrOut.ContentType = "text/xml";
            hwrOut.Headers.Set("Translate", "f");

            b = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString());

            hwrOut.ContentLength = b.Length;

            s = hwrOut.GetRequestStream();
            s.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
            s.Close();

            hwrIn = (HttpWebResponse)hwrOut.GetResponse();


            hwrOut = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(sMailboxTemp + "/" + Path.GetFileName(sAttach));
            hwrOut.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            hwrOut.Method = "PUT";

            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(sAttach, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                b = new Byte[fs.Length];

                fs.Read(b, 0, (Int32)fs.Length);
            }

            hwrOut.ContentLength = b.Length;

            s = hwrOut.GetRequestStream();
            s.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
            s.Close();

            hwrIn = (HttpWebResponse)hwrOut.GetResponse();
        }
        #endregion



        // Create the HttpWebRequest object.
        hwrOut = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(sMailboxTemp);
        hwrOut.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        hwrOut.Method = "MOVE";
        hwrOut.Headers.Add("Destination", sMailboxSend);

        hwrIn = (HttpWebResponse)hwrOut.GetResponse();

        // Clean up.
        hwrIn.Close();
    }
```